# Render CSS, either from @Input or object property

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

We have an RTF control in our main application (standalone) which also generates CSS classes, and HTML that uses these classes. This is being loaded via an API.

It's outputted like this:

```
.cs95E872D0{} .csCF6BBF71{font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}
```

and the HTML is outputted like so:

```
<p class="cs95E872D0"><span class="csCF6BBF71">this is a test</span></p>
```

It's terribly formatted but I guess that's what you get with auto-generated stuff! We are unable to change the generation of this CSS/HTML so unfortunately this is what I have to work with.

I need to display this HTML on a page (easy enough with the `[innerHTML]` attribute) however when it comes to doing it with the CSS I can't seem to figure it out.

I've tried creating a new component:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'htmlrender',
    template: `<span [innerHtml]="html"></span>`,
    styles: ['{{styles}}']
})
export class TestComponent {
    @Input() html: string;
    @Input() styles: string;
}
```

However it gets rendered as this:

```
<htmlrender _ngcontent-c9="" _nghost-c11="" ng-reflect-styles=".cs95E872D0{} .csCF6BBF71{font">
    <span _ngcontent-c11=""></span>
</htmlrender>
```

Which doesn't work. I've also just tried to render the CSS inside `<style>` tags but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can't use template interpolation in not-a-template, and think about the lifecycle of the component.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sure, but is there a way to render CSS obtained from an API call, onto a page in angular 2/4?

Comment: Could you expand on rendering the CSS within style elements? Give a [mcve] - did you use the DOM sanitizer?

Answer (score 0):

If the output is always the same you can use a string.slice() and string.replace().

I did it like this:

```
this.str = '.cs95E872D0{} .csCF6BBF71{font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}';
let slice = this.str.split(".", 3);
console.log('.' + slice[1]);
console.log('.' + slice[2]);
```

They output of slice[1] and slice[2] look like:

`.cs95E872D0{}`

`.csCF6BBF71{font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}`

Comment: Unfortunately the output will not always be the same. Also, it's not just about seperating the classes but rendering it inside <style> tags on the DOM.

Comment: Then it will be hard to achieve.
Angular is based on JSON or XML if you work with backend.

Try on the backend to reply with JSON that way it will be easier to work with.